# Changed design now no buttons work

Tags: c#, button, onclick

I've changed the master page design to update to a nice new one for a site, however since doing that none of the form submit buttons are working. I can't even being to work out how to debug this. The HTML for the onclick is there, but it doesn't seem to be hitting

The input is the exact same as the original. I set a breakpoint on the onclick event in the code but it's not hit. Any suggestions will be really welcome.

Edit: Here is the ASP / HTMl

Company Name:

```
   <div class="field">
    <label>Type of Business:</label>
     <asp:TextBox Text="" ID="GSU_BussinessType" CssClass="" runat="server"/>
    </div>
     <div class="field">
    <label>First Name:</label>
     <asp:TextBox Text="" ID="GSU_FirstName" CssClass="" runat="server"/>
    </div>
     <div class="field">
    <label>Last Name:</label>
     <asp:TextBox Text="" ID="GSU_LastName" CssClass="" runat="server"/>
    </div>
     <div class="field">
    <label>Mobile Number:</label>
     <asp:TextBox Text="" ID="GSU_Mobile" CssClass="" runat="server"/>
    </div>
     <div class="field">
    <label>Email Address:</label>
     <asp:TextBox Text="" ID="GSU_Email" CssClass="" runat="server"/>
    </div>
     <div class="field">
    <label>User Name:</label>
     <asp:TextBox Text="" ID="GSU_Username" CssClass="" runat="server"/>
    </div>
     <div class="field">
    <label>Password:</label>
     <asp:TextBox Text="" ID="GSU_Password" autocomplete="off" runat="server" TextMode="Password"/>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="Button" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" text="Submit" onclick="Unnamed1_Click" Class="button color"/>
```

Comment: Are you using ASP controls? That looks like a rendered `<asp:Button />`.

Comment: Yeah I am, it's all ASP controls

Comment: It might be more helpful to post the ASP code, then, rather than the rendered HTML.

Comment: Seems obvious but worth asking: have you removed your form tags by accident?

Comment: The form tags are on the master page or the c#, theres no form around the actual form (there never was)

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Had another form hiding in my master page using get! Grr!